Sorting keys in a dictionary with multiple keys while keeping certain keys together
I have a Dictionary with keys of type Setting, where setting is a struct with members mCategory (String), mIndex (int), and mDescription (String). Some of the keys are unique - there will be at most one with the same mCategory. These have mIndex set to -INF and their descriptions are arbitrary.
The other keys will follow a sequence, e.g., items in mCategory Books can have mIndex 1, 2, 3 etc. Descriptions are not arbitrary for the latter. They are prefixed with mCategory + mIndex. I want the keys to be sorted by description, until we are at a non-unique mCategory. I want to sort the keys with the same mCategory by mIndex because sorting the whole thing lexicographically would place Book 10 after Book 1. This is what I want - but I cannot figure out how to make it sort the way I want



Description
Index
Type




ABC
-INF
X


BCD
-INF
Y


CDE
-INF
Z


D 1
1
D


D 2
2
D


D 3
3
D


D 4
4
D


..
..
..


D 10
10
D


EGH
-INF
E


GHI
..
F


K 1
..
K


K 2
..
K



This is the comparator I wrote but this is clearly not working:
bool operator()(const myStruct& rLeft, const myStruct& rRight) const
{
        if (rLeft.mCategory == rRight.mCategory)
             return rLeft.mIndex < rRight.mIndex;
        else return rLeft.mDescription.CompareNoCase(rRight.m_sDescription) < 0;  
}

Clarification:
I don't want to sort by uniqueness, I want to sort by description until sorting by description finds a non-unique category, then sort that subsequence by index, then continue sorting by description until another non-unique subsequence occurs, and so on. I fixed the example to reflect that.

Don't describe your code, just show the code as a [mre].

The easiest way to ensure that you have a valid comparison over multiple criteria is to always use std::tuple::operator<, synthesizing values that represent your priority of order.
bool operator()(const myStruct& rLeft, const myStruct& rRight) const
{
    return std::tuple{ lhs.index == -1 ? lhs.description : lhs.type, lhs.index }
         < std::tuple{ rhs.index == -1 ? rhs.description : rhs.type, rhs.index };
}

This orders elements of a non-unique category together, by ignoring their description, and uses the index to order within the category.

Thanks for the pointer but I don't actually want to sort by uniqueness, I want to sort by description until sorting by description finds a non-unique category, then sort that subsequence by index, then continue sorting by description until another non-unique subsequence occurs, and so on.

Oh, your example is confusing then. I'd change it to have elements after the Ds

@ArannyaMonzur are you sure your existing code is wrong? It does require the descriptions do have the structure you describe

I fixed the example, thanks for the suggestion. My code unfortunately does not ensure the correct order if keys are inserted arbitrarily. It's possible for keys of the same category to be placed non-consecutively without violating the conditions I used.

@ArannyaMonzur something like this?

That's pretty much what I was looking for! Thank you so much.
